# Error selecting rows from datatable in jsf 2.2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, selection, rows

I have a datatable with a checkbox column to select some rows, when the user is logged everything works fine but when the user is not logged the list with the selected rows are empty after the post, i cant figure it out because this is done automatically by the datatable component, it has nothing to do with the fact that the user is logged or no, maybe it is a bug in jsf 2.2? I'm using the datatable from primefaces 5.

```
public CompareReportBean() {
    rowsToCompare = List<TabelaEmpresa>)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get("rowsToCompare");

    WorksheetService ws = new WorksheetService();
    for(TabelaEmpresa t : rowsToCompare) {
        t.setColunas(ws.retrieveColumnsFromTable(t));
    }        

    columnKeys = new ColunaTabela[rowsToCompare.size()];
}
```

When the user is logged rowsToCompare contains the rows selected by the user, and when the user is not logged rowsToCompare is empty, but the code executed is the same in both situations.

Comment: Hi, didn't find anything that could be doing this, but what the filter could be doing to modify the post variable?

Comment: I used the web developer tools from firefox to see the post header and it's identical in both situations. This is the trouble with jsf it's difficult to debug when you have a problem.
I'm not using any filters in this page.

Comment: can you post your xhtml code and if using datamodel to provide datamodel code else what exactly you are using for rowKey attribute